# JSON, MYSQL, SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Есть объекты JSON в бд следующего типа:

```
{
    "0": {
        "rating": -1,
        "user": 1
    },
    "1": {
        "rating": -1,
        "user": 2
    },
    "2": {
        "rating": 1,
        "user": 3
    },
    "3": {
        "rating": 1,
        "user": 4
    }
}
```

Как с помощью SELECT можно изъять кол-во "rating" = -1/1? И оптимально ли вообще хранить подобные сведения в json или лучше заводить отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Замените пример данных на скрипты CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (ещё лучше - создайте fiddle). И покажите результат, который хотите получить от сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить количество записей Вы можете при помощи `COUNT` в mysql.
Для того, чтобы искать данные по ключу в `json`, можно воспользоваться `JSON_CONTAINS`:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`param`, '{\"rating\":1}')"
```

Где первым параметром мы указываем название столбца (В примере `param`), а вторым значением указываем искомый ключ со значением.

В примере будет выведено количество записей в БД, где в столбце `param` будет находиться `json` объект, в котором будет одним из ключей будет являться `rating` а его значением будет `1`.

Пример данных в таблице:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целом, может эксперты скажут точнее, но лучше делать записи отдельно по ключам для наибольшего удобства и скорости поиска. 
Но, Вы вполне можете искать данные и в `json` объектах записей в БД.

Comment: Спасибо, надо попробовать. Я не понимал, как работает функция JSON_CONTAINS и как с её помощью искать что-то, но тот пример, что вы привели, может сработать.